# How can I combine separate dictionary outputs from a function in one dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

For our python project we have to solve multiple questions. We are however stuck at this one:

"Write a function that, given a FASTA file name, returns a dictionary with the sequence IDs as keys, and a tuple as value. The value denotes the minimum and maximum molecular weight for the sequence (sequences can be ambiguous)."

```
import collections
    from Bio import Seq
    from itertools import product
    def ListMW(file_name):
        seq_records = SeqIO.parse(file_name, 'fasta',alphabet=generic_dna)
        for record in seq_records:
            dictionary = Seq.IUPAC.IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values
            result = []
            for i in product(*[dictionary[j] for j in record]):
                result.append("".join(i))
                molw = []
            for sequence in result:
                molw.append(SeqUtils.molecular_weight(sequence))
            tuple= (min(molw),max(molw))
            if min(molw)==max(molw):
                dict={record.id:molw}
            else:
                dict={record.id:(min(molw), max(molw))}

            print(dict)
```

Using this code we manage to get this output:

```
{'seq_7009': (6236.9764, 6367.049999999999)}
{'seq_418': (3716.3642000000004, 3796.4124000000006)}
{'seq_9143_unamb': [4631.958999999999]}
{'seq_2888': (5219.3359, 5365.4089)}
{'seq_1101': (4287.7417, 4422.8254)}
{'seq_107': (5825.695099999999, 5972.8073)}
{'seq_6946': (5179.3118, 5364.420900000001)}
{'seq_6162': (5531.503199999999, 5645.577399999999)}
{'seq_504': (4556.920899999999, 4631.959)}
{'seq_3535': (3396.1715999999997, 3446.1969999999997)}
{'seq_4077': (4551.9108, 4754.0073)}
{'seq_1626_unamb': [3724.3894999999998]}
```

As you can see this is not one dictionary but multiple dictionaries under each other. So is there anyway we can change our code or type an extra command to get it in this format:

```
{'seq_7009': (6236.9764, 6367.049999999999),
'seq_418': (3716.3642000000004, 3796.4124000000006),
'seq_9143_unamb': (4631.958999999999),
'seq_2888': (5219.3359, 5365.4089),
'seq_1101': (4287.7417, 4422.8254),
'seq_107': (5825.695099999999, 5972.8073),
'seq_6946': (5179.3118, 5364.420900000001),
'seq_6162': (5531.503199999999, 5645.577399999999),
'seq_504': (4556.920899999999, 4631.959),
'seq_3535': (3396.1715999999997, 3446.1969999999997),
'seq_4077': (4551.9108, 4754.0073),
'seq_1626_unamb': (3724.3894999999998)}
```

Or in someway manage to make clear that it should use the seq_ID ans key and the Molecular weight as a value for one dictionary?

Comment: You might need to use `update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a **dictionnary** right before your for loop, then update it during your loop such as :

```
import collections
    from Bio import Seq
    from itertools import product
    def ListMW(file_name):
        seq_records = SeqIO.parse(file_name, 'fasta',alphabet=generic_dna)
        retDict = {}
        for record in seq_records:
            dictionary = Seq.IUPAC.IUPACData.ambiguous_dna_values
            result = []
            for i in product(*[dictionary[j] for j in record]):
                result.append("".join(i))
                molw = []
            for sequence in result:
                molw.append(SeqUtils.molecular_weight(sequence))
            tuple= (min(molw),max(molw))
            if min(molw)==max(molw):
                retDict[record.id] = molw
            else:
                retDict[record.id] = (min(molw), max(molw))}
            # instead of printing now, print in the end of your function / script
            # print(dict)
```

Right now, you're setting a **new dict** at each turn of your loop, and print it. It is just a normal behaviour of your code to print lots and lots of dict.

Comment: Thank you this worked! we got almost the output we need :)

Comment: You're welcome, but @Jean-François Fabre also deserves your upvote. He also gave an hint as to how to optimize your code.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm trying to like it and yours however I'm not able to because I'm a new user...

Answer (score 1):

you're creating a dictionary with 1 entry at each iteration.

You want to:

- define a `dict` variable (better use `dct` to avoid reusing built-in type name) before your loop
- rewrite the assignment to `dict` in the loop

So before the loop:

```
dct = {}
```

and in the loop (instead of your `if` + `dict =` code), in a ternary expression, with min & max computed only once:

```
minval = min(molw)
maxval = max(molw)
dct[record.id] = molw if minval == maxval else (minval,maxval)
```